# How to pass argument inside forever while running nodejs in ubuntu for HTTPs private key passphrase

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, https, private-key, forever

I am running nodejs and using forever to forever run file.

Today i have changed code of node and introduced https module in it and given my private key path to it.

Now whenever i start nodejs it asks me for passphrase of private key.
But now my issue is how to pass this passphrase in forever process.

Answer (score 1):

this may be too late for you but it may be useful for anyone's reference in future.

you cannot pass an argument to provide a pass-phrase for your key file in forever but you can achieve that when creating the server. see the following example for more:

```
https.createServer({
        key: privateKey.pem,
        passphrase:'your-passphrase',
        cert: publicCertificate.pem
    }, app);
```

node js will automatically enter the pass-phrase and run the server in secure mode.